Understanding Statistical Manifolds for Discrete Events vs Continuous Sample Spaces
Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where:

$\Omega$ is the sample space
$\mathcal{F} = \{A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5\}$ is a finite $\sigma$-algebra
$P$ is a probability measure

We want to construct a statistical manifold for parametric probability distributions over this space.

In this discrete setting, is the statistical manifold $\mathcal{M}$ composed of:
a) Probability density functions over the entire $\Omega$?
b) Discrete probability distributions over the events in $\mathcal{F}$?

If we choose option b), how would we represent a point on this manifold? Would it be correct to write:
$p(\theta) = (p(A_1; \theta), p(A_2; \theta), p(A_3; \theta), p(A_4; \theta), p(A_5; \theta))$
where $\theta$ is a parameter (or set of parameters) and $\sum_{i=1}^5 p(A_i; \theta) = 1$ for all $\theta$?

How does this discrete case differ from the continuous case often discussed in information geometry, where we typically work with probability density functions over a continuous sample space?

In the context of information geometry and statistical manifolds, when papers refer to "the space of all probability distributions," are they typically referring to distributions over the entire sample space $\Omega$ or over a specific $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$?


I'm trying to reconcile the theory of statistical manifolds with practical scenarios where we often work with probabilities of specific events rather than density functions over a continuous space. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!
